# In Emacs, is there a way to run shell-command without displaying output?

Tags: emacs, elisp

For example, in Emacs, using shell-command to call a perl script,

```
 M-! perl my_script.pl
```

or call a simple external command,

```
M-! dir
```

I do not want to display any output in the command window of Emacs.

PS: my operating system is Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux:

```
M-! perl my_script.pl>/dev/null
```

Windows:

```
M-! perl my_script.pl> NUL
```

This will not return output.

Comment: I'm sorry I forget to mention that my question is not restrict to call perl. And my system is Windows.